# Using Bash To Recursively download the files from SFTP server

Tags: bash, curl, sftp

I'm given with a SFTP server IP ADDRESS | User Name | Password. Each day , The SFTP server might have some N number of zips in the format of "2016_11_02_1.zip". I knew, How to to download the files using cURL.

```
$curl -u xxxxx:xxxxx sftp://x.x.x.x/path/to/2016_11_02_1.zip
$curl -u xxxxx:xxxxx sftp://x.x.x.x/path/to/2016_11_02_2.zip
```

Now , I will write a script to download the available zip files on the SFTP server ( 2016_11_02_1.zip , 2016_11_02_2.zip , 2016_11_02_3.zip ). After few hours later , The SFTP server might be added with `2016_11_02_4.zip ..... 2016_11_02_30.zip.`

How can i download the files without downloading the already downloaded ZIP files `( 2016_11_02_1.zip , 2016_11_02_2.zip , 2016_11_02_3.zip )`.

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Can you access the server via ssh? If so, then I would suggest `rsync`.

Comment: @Cyrus Yes , I can access via ssh. I will have a look into rsync too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still have the previously downloaded files? If so, you can check that the there's already a file with that name exists on your local disk.

Comment: Yes i will have the previous downloaded files.  Now , I will have to compare the files on my local disk as well as the SFTP server. If any thing in common , skip that and download the Non-existing ones.

Comment: Sounds right. Can you mark my answer as correct then?

Answer (score 1):

If by SFTP you mean secure FTP you can just use rsync with SSH support (>=3.X I think), since SFTP is part of SSH. Example:

```
rsync -av user@nowhere.com:/path/to/`date +%Y`*
```